# Get last login time from SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, union-all

I need to display only last login time user data, data being - name, email, location and datetime.

Scenario is user registers him/her self for the first time and login datetime gets inserted in to `eventonline.participant` table...now for subsequent login of the same user only we save logintime into `eventonline.logindatetime`.

Below is the query I used, but it selects all users login data instead of last login datetime.

```
select 
    a.firstname as Name, 
    a.Email as Email, 
    a.Address1 as Location, 
    a.MobileNo as Contact, 
    a.datetime, a.ID 
from 
    eventonline.participant a 
where 
    a.eventid = '" + Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["event_id"]) + "'

union 

select 
    a.firstname as Name, 
    a.Email as Email, 
    a.Address1 as Location, 
    a.MobileNo as Contact, 
    b.datetime, b.Rid 
from 
    eventonline.participant a 
join 
    eventonline.logindatetime b on a.Id = b.Rid 
where 
    b.eventid = '" + Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["event_id"]) + "'  
order by 
    datetime desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **Database** : eventonline
, **Table names** : participant, logindatetime

**Let say your participant table contains following data :-**

registration_id | user_phone | user_email | first_name | last_name | created_timestamp

1 | 5545555454 | test1@test.com | tom | dave | 2016-03-05 21:33:55

2 | 5599992154 | test123@test.com | riya | bottom | 2016-03-05 15:33:55

3 | 5545876954 | test123@test.com |greg | george | 2016-03-09 12:32:55

**And logindatetime table have following data :-**

id | registration_id | ip_address | user_Agent | created_timestamp

1 | 2 | 10.2.3.101 | mozilla | 2016-03-05 15:54:11

2 | 3 | 10.0.5.99 | chrome | 2016-03-15 23:31:01

3 | 1 | 10.0.4.43 | safari | 2016-04-01 21:33:55

4 | 2 | 10.2.4.65 | mozilla | 2016-04-05 19:21:55

5 | 1 | 10.6.5.54 | chrome | 2016-04-11 19:12:15

Now if you want to retrieve the user data along with login data corresponding to the 5th row i.e the latest row in logindatetime time then below query will work.

**select a.registration_id, a.user_phone, a.user_email , a.first_name, a.last_name,  b.ip_address, b.user_Agent, b.created_timestamp from participant as a JOIN logindatetime as b where a.registration_id=b.registration_id order by b.created_timestamp desc limit 1;**

**Result**

registration_id | user_phone | user_email | first_name | last_name  ip_address | user_Agent | created_timestamp

1 | 5545555454 | test1@test.com | tom | dave | 10.6.5.54 | chrome | 2016-04-11 19:12:15

Comment: `limit 1` with `SQL Server 2008`?

Comment: Okay, if its SQL server then user SELECT TOP 1 in the beginning of query and remove limit 1 part from above query.

Comment: `from participant as a JOIN logindatetime as b where a.registration_id=b.registration_id` JOIN require `ON` not `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about writing the query to do it.
I have used the rank over function in sql to grab only the last or first values in a partition of data I want to look at.

```
    SELECT
*
FROM
 (
    select 
      -- Here is the magic that makes it work.
      Rank() over (Partition BY a.Email order by a.datetime DESC) as Rank
      a.firstname as Name, 
      a.Email as Email, 
      a.Address1 as Location, 
      a.MobileNo as Contact, 
      a.datetime,
      a.ID 
   FROM 
    <YourFromCause>   
 ) 
 -- naming the temp result set.
 tmp
where 
  Rank = 1
```